# Counting Comparisions in Quicksort: Wrong answer

Tags: c, sorting, quicksort

I have written code to compute the number of comparisons done in QuickSort.

The algorithm increases the count of comparisons by m-1 whenever a quicksort is performed on an array of length m (Since pivot will be compared with everything other than itself).

The choice of the pivot is always the first element of the array.

When I try to use it on an array of 10000 entries, it is giving me a wrong answer.

A correct answer is supposed to be **162085**.

The link to the dataset is given below:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0D_kFnzj_RrYm9NT0lrM3JfN2c/view?usp=sharing

The total comparisons are stored in x.

```
 #include<stdio.h>
  long long x=0;
  int size=10000;
  int A[10000];
  int B[10000];

  void quicksort(int A[],int begin,int end)
  {
  if(begin<end){
  int i=begin;
  int j=end;
  int k;
  int pivot=begin;

  for(k=begin+1;k<=end;k++)
  {
  if(A[k]>A[pivot])
  {
  x++;
  B[j]=A[k];
  j--;
  }
  else
  {
  x++;
  B[i]=A[k];
  i++;
  }
  }

  B[i]=A[pivot];

  for(k=begin;k<=end;k++)
  {
  A[k]=B[k];
  }

  quicksort(A,begin,i-1);
  quicksort(A,i+1,end);
  }
  else
  {
  if((end-begin)==1) x++;
  }
  }

  int main()
  {

  FILE *myFile;
  myFile = fopen("QuickSort.txt", "r");


  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
  {
  fscanf(myFile, "%d", &A[i]);
  }

  quicksort(A,0,size-1);

  for(i=0;i<size;i++)
  {
  printf("%d\n",A[i]);
  }

  printf("%lld",x);
  }
```

Comment: Wrong answer means -1, is it? Or 42?

Comment: btw: quicksort is an inplace algorithm, so you can let it run on your array you don't need to copy everything

Comment: I uploaded the wrong code earlier. I am so so sorry.

Comment: Please look at the present version of the code and see if you can find any mistakes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this part is wrong:

```
for(k=begin+1;k<=end;k++)
{
    if(A[k]>A[pivot])
    {
        x++;
        B[j]=A[k];
        j--;
    }
    else
    {
        x++;
        B[i]=A[k];
        i++;
    }
}
```

you don't have to go from begin till end. you only should go from begin till i>j.

see link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort

there the interesting lines are:

```
do
    i := i + 1
while A[i] < pivot
do
    j := j – 1
while A[j] > pivot
if i >= j then
    return j
swap A[i] with A[j]
```

**c / c++**

```
i = begin;
j = end;
while(true)
{
    while(i< end && A[i] < A[pivot])
    {
        i++;
    }
    while(j> begin && A[j] >= A[pivot])
    {
        j--;
    }
    if(i<j)
    {
        int temp = A[i]; //std::swap(A[i],A[j]);
        A[i] = A[j];
        A[j] = temp;
    else
    {
       break;
    }
}
```

In this code I don't use B because quicksort is an "inplace" algorithm and because of that we don't need to save the result into a different array